# Transformer 220 to 110 ac

Tags: transformer

for a 220V/50Hz, 2.8 A, 500W what is the Amps equivalent for 110V/ 60 Hz? Using a 220V /110 V step down transformer with Hz converter included.

Comment: Such a device is more than a transformer if it converts Hz. You should refer to the manufacturer's data.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a link to the datasheet (not an Amazon or Ali-whats-it advert) for the device in question. If it changes mains frequency then it is not a transformer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is presumed that 220V~ 50Hz 2.8A 500W is the rating on the nameplate of a piece of equipment. The rating on the nameplate of an identical piece of equipment, intended for 110V~ 60Hz operation, would be 110V~ 60Hz 5.6A 500W.